# JTree Search not searching for non expanded nodes

Tags: java, swing, search, jtree

```
public final DefaultMutableTreeNode findNode(String searchString) {

    java.util.List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> searchNodes = getSearchNodes((DefaultMutableTreeNode)deviceTreeView.getModel().getRoot());
    DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)deviceTreeView.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

    DefaultMutableTreeNode foundNode = null;
    int bookmark = -1;

    if( currentNode != null ) {
        for(int index = 0; index < searchNodes.size(); index++) {
            if( searchNodes.get(index) == currentNode ) {
                bookmark = index;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int index = bookmark + 1; index < searchNodes.size(); index++) {    
        if(searchNodes.get(index).toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
            foundNode = searchNodes.get(index);
            break;
        }
    }

    if( foundNode == null ) {
        for(int index = 0; index <= bookmark; index++) {    
            if(searchNodes.get(index).toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
                foundNode = searchNodes.get(index);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return foundNode;
}   

private final java.util.List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> getSearchNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
    java.util.List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> searchNodes = new java.util.ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();

    java.util.Enumeration<?> e = root.preorderEnumeration();
    while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
        searchNodes.add((DefaultMutableTreeNode)e.nextElement());
    }
    return searchNodes;
}
```

It works for 2 levels and works if all are expanded. For non-expanded items it is not searching if depth is more than 2.

Comment: Are the child nodes dynamically generated when the parent node is expanded?

Comment: it would be extremely useful to see how the nodes are being created - the posted code seems to be working fine for a 'statically' generated tree (depth 4).